# GitLab CI - Setting up the GitLab Runner for CI/CD

Tags: gitlab

I was setting up the GitLab Runner on another server system . I faced an error in the Registration step. The error said ‘having a network problem’.

The detailed description of the error is
“ERROR: Registering runner… failed . Couldn’t execute POST against http://gitlab.sw.st
ratus.com/api/v4/runners: Post http://gitlab.sw.stratus.com/api/v4/runners: dial
tcp 134.111.200.59:80: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.”

The thing is the server system on which I am trying to set up the GitLab Runner uses the port 80 for talking to an Apache server. Is there any way, I can make the GitLab Runner dial a connection on any other port apart from 80?

Regards,
Poornima

Answer (score 0):

You should modify `advertise_address` and `listen_address` in your Runner configuration.

```
[session_server]
  listen_address = "0.0.0.0:8093"
  advertise_address = "gitlab.com:8093"
```

[Check here](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/configuration/advanced-configuration.html#the-session_server-section) to get the full documentation.

Comment: Hello thanks for the help! But, I do not have a config.toml yet. I am still doing the registration step. While enter the tags associated with the Runner, and about to answer the pop-up question, "whether to lock the Runner to current project[true/false]?" this network connection problem arises. I am not able to set up the Runner at all. Please let me know if you can understand my situation and are aware of the solution.

Comment: Hi You're welcome! I think I had a similar problem like the one you have right now. You need a token in the configuration for the runner to work. And that token generated when you register a runner into Gitlab server. A workaround could be register another runner somewhere else and use its token (you can delete it after). Another way is to temporarily stop the apache server, register the runner for the token, reconfigure the runner and start the apache server again.

Comment: Oh let me try the workaround if that is possible! Thanks anyway for the help.